# include a preamble in a standalone

Tags: graphics, include, standalone, preamble

I need to make many images wich uses the same preamble. To make those images, I use the document class standalone. My aim would be to create a file preamble.tex and to include it in the other files, like this :

```
%preamble.tex
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}

%drawing tools
```

and

```
%image.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\include{preamble}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%draw my picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. 'Doesn't work' is not terribly informative. Do you get an error? Does your computer explode? Does it compile but with blank output? You probably want `\input` rather than `\include`, by the way.

Comment: Actually, it works fine for me with `\input` rather than `\include`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `\input` rather than `\include` for cases such as this where it is not a whole part of a document which might be compiled alone (e.g. a chapter or section or something). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for details. Note, in particular, that you cannot use `\include` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{preamble}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {ABC};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, do as  David Carlisle recommends and make the preamble into a package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads pgf

\endinput
```

And then just load it as with any other package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mypreamble}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {ABC};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't really understand why this is 'more logical' than using `\input` but, then, I am far from expert.

Comment: even better would be to rename `preamble.tex` to `mysetup.sty` and use `\usepackage{mysetup}` instead of `\input` (well actually it makes no difference to TeX but it's logically better)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why? I'm interested partly because I tend to use `\input` in this kind of case i.e. where what I'm feeding in is a fairly rigid list of packages and configurations intended for use in a single project involving a number of documents needing a consistent look. (For example, all sets of slides or all draft handouts for a module.) If it is generic enough that I want it in `~/texmf`, then I tend to make it a package or a `.cfg` or whatever. If it is staying in the project's directories, I tend not to. What is the proper way to draw the distinction?

Comment: I think it's best to view the preamble as essentially an "anonymous package" where a small amount of local setup can be placed, so once that becomes big enough to be a a separate file a package is the natural choice. it's just a name really, you could use `\makeatletter\input{longtable.sty}` there's no difference really except for `\ProvidesPackage` which is just a message feature. So I'd always use `\usepackage`  in the preamble and `\input` or `\include` in the main document, for document content rather than macros.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Don't you find it confusing to have packages which are not in a `texmf` tree?

Comment: I have copies of longtable, color, blkarray, .... not in the main tree for some reason, a few more don't seem odd at all, no. If the configuration is applicable to several of your documents put it in the local texmf if it is just for one put it with the document.